# Show that we can find a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ s.t. the Fourier transform of $f$, $\hat{f}=1$ in some neighborhood of $0.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

How can we find a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ s.t. the Fourier transform of $f$, $\hat{f}=1$ in some neighborhood of $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using bump functions, you can construct a compactly supported, smooth function that equals $1$ in some neighborhood of $0$.
2. The Fourier transform is a bijection on the space of radily decreasing functions.

Comment: So 1 follows by existence of bump functions as detailed on the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#Existence_of_bump_functions?

Comment: And how does 2 imply the result? More detail then less would be good - my analysis knowledge is kind of barebone.

Comment: The Fourier transform is a bijection on the space of rapidly decreasing functions, so in particuiar it is surjective and the function from 1. is an element of the codomain, so what does the definition of surjectivity imply?

Comment: So we can find some $\hat{g}$ that has the same properties as the $f$ in 1. To clarify understanding: (a) For that $f$, this does not mean $\hat{f}$ is the thing we are looking for, it is some other functions fourier transform $\hat{g}$?

Comment: Also (b) if we are interested in $L^1(R^n)$, how does it suffice to talk about the space of rapidly decreasing functions? Would I need to show that the bump functions are in the space of rapidly decreasing functions and $L^1$ (and $L^1 \subset$ space of rapidly decreasing functions)? Would we also need invariance of the fourier transform on $L^1$ to conclude this?

Comment: (a): 1. says there is a function $f\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which equals $1$ in a neighborhood of $0$, 2. says there is a function $g\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\hat{g}=f$. This $g$ is what we are looking for. (b): $S(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.